# italics spilling over to the rest of the text

Tags: equations, italic

I have a simple line here:

```
Let training data \textit{X} consist of x_{i...n} observations, where....
```

The intention is to let *x* have subscript *i..n*. This happens, however, after x_i..n, all the following text becomes italicized too, like this:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: `$x_{i...n}$  obs`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You get an error message from that input: don't ignore them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you show produces an error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

when TeX finds `_`, because this character is legal only in math mode. The output from then on can not be relied unto. Fix errors as soon as they are raised when processing the file.

Your input should be

```
Let the training data \(X\) consist of \(x_{i\dots n}\) observations, where
\(n\) is the number of training data samples, \(X\) represents the feature
vectors of
```

Note how math symbols are properly surrounded by `\(...\)` which makes TeX typeset them in math mode (applying italics where needed automatically).

Comment: How can OP understand the error message "Missing $ inserted" when there is no `$` in your answer? It is typical that LaTeX uses different markup and different terminology than TeX itself. And the users are confused:).

Comment: @wipet Reading a good LaTeX guide suffices.

Comment: Reading a good TeX giude suffices too. Moreover, the reader need not to use LaTeX after such reading.